# ng-deep not working when switching between components?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, frontend

I have 2 components A B , in each component's css file I have a ngx-bootstrap datepicker which i need to customize ( align ).

In A component css file I have

```
 ::ng-deep .bs-datepicker { 
margin-top:-100px
}
```

In B component css file I have

```
::ng-deep .bs-datepicker { 
margin-top:-80px
}
```

When I go to component A and inspect element it shows A's css file, which is what i want,
But when go to component B and then come back to component A , It shows B's Css file in Component A, so it shows margin-top:80px in Component A.

How do I segregate styling between these two components without one affecting the other when i switch from one component to other?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `bs-datepicker` in a container and use it name to capture

```
::ng-deep .container-one * .bs-datepicker { 
margin-top:-100px
} 

::ng-deep .container-two *  .bs-datepicker { 
margin-top:-80px
}
```

and in HTML files:

```
<div class="container-one">
    <input type="text" bsDatePicker>
</div>

<div class="container-two">
    <input type="text" bsDatePicker>
</div>
```

Those will have different styling

I also recommend stopping using ::ng-deep to prevent unexpected behaviours (just like you had in this situation).

The approach above will also work on `styles.scss` file without the `::ng-deep` with the correct `angular.json` configuration

Comment: I had styles.css before for this arrangement but I need different margin-top values for these 2 components. with styles.css it is only assuming one style for all the components.

The HTML is <input type="text" bsDatePicker>, i dont have <bs-datepicker> in my html 
Whats the * between container and bs-datepicker for?
Thanks though.

Comment: About the HTML tags - I've edited - it's the same styling. the * means every HTML element under container-one, so .container-one * .bs-datepicker means: every element with class bs-datepicker under container-one, so as long you are separating with different container classes names it will be ok!

Comment: The * works in .css files too right? It is not working for me. i have put ``::ng-deep .container-one * .bs-datepicke`` in .css file

Comment: I have several datepickers in the container, can that be a reason why its not working?

Comment: No it should work. maybe you had a type and forgot the r in `.bs-datepicke`? ,Can you share your HTML relevant code?\

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7pazr0xb/ Please check this out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234901/discussion-between-chepeharshit-and-erez-s).